# Using Sentence-Bert with other features in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow, bert

I have a dataset where one feature is text and 4 more features. Sentence-Bert vectorizer transforms text data into tensors. I can use these sparse matrices directly with a machine learning classifier. Can I replace the text column with tensors? Also how can I train the model. Below is the code I used to transform the text into vectors.

```
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/LaBSE')
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(X_train['tweet'], convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True)
sentence_embeddings1 = model.encode(X_test['tweet'], convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True)
```

Comment: one can linearize the tensors into a big 1d array of numbers and concat this array to other features and train